# Yes/No permission required

Tags: vba, msgbox

I have created a VBA and have tried to add a MsgBox to confirm I do want to continue. The MsgBox appears but does not respond if I click OK or X.I was hoping to be given a Yes/No choice.

Sub Clear_sheet()

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
 Dim AnswerYes As String
 Dim AnswerNo As String
 AnswerYes = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbQuestion + YesNo, "User Response")
If AnswerYes = vbYes Then
  Range("T32 , AB32").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range("B4:B32").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range("W11").Select
Else
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

End Sub

My code also has many more ranges to ClearContents. I'm wondering if the VBA will be improved with fewer lines with the ranges separated with a comma?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer I needed on Google

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password here"
Dim AnswerYes As String
Dim AnswerNo As String
AnswerYes = MsgBox("Do you wish to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")
If AnswerYes = vbYes Then

```
  Code to action entered here

 Else
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect "Password here"
```

End Sub